# storing mysql results into $_SESSION[] variables

Tags: php, mysql, session, resultset

Hello I want to now your opinion about this strategy.

My goal is to load whole mysql table into `$_SESSION[]` on page first run and then get values (for example text) from here to save number of mysql requests. Connected together with AJAX (if js enabled) techniques to retrieve data my goal is fluent and fast website.

I know about disadvantages as for example new content will not appear to user until new session is set, but I want to know if I didn't miss something elementary against using this technique.

Comment: purpose of session for storing temp data, it may not be efficient to hold entire table...

Comment: I would use local storage with ajax and forget sessions as you still have to send that same data to the user/browser for it to be of any use.

Comment: Local storage seems to be good idea but what about non-html5 browsers ? Make entire page in JS and store texts in JS variables ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good Idea to load table data into session as:

1. Data can be huge
2. Data may change in the db, but you have old data into the session
3. Session expires after a time period
4. Too many big sessions means to many big variables on the server.... To much memory required by the server.
5. User need not logout of the system but will close its browser and go. In this case the session still remains active on the server for some time.

So its a very bad idea to keep entire data into the session. Just keep the data that you need regularly and has least possibility of getting changed.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea. Because of some reason :

1. Suppose your table size become very big.
2. $_SESSION data will expire after *session.gc_maxlifetime* seconds of inactivity.

If your table size is not growing then you can go ahead and store data in $_SESSION.